# Htaccess Rule Conflict

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, conflict

I wrote a few htaccess rules. But there exist a confliction. I couldn't solve the problem.

```
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/(.+).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rule for languages /en/login.php = > /login.php?lang=en etc.

Besides i had another rule

```
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/playlist\.xml$ includes/xml/mediaxml.php?album=$1
```

This rule is for demo music albums. album/ID/playlist.xml = > includes/xml/mediaxml.php?album=$1

Our customers can listen musics with this playlists. I wrote playlist.xml rule before.

When i added language supports. I noticed this problem. How can i solve it ?

Do you have any idea ?

Edit:

All .htaccess codes

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dunyaturizm\.com\.tr$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dunyaturizm.com.tr/$1 [R=301,L]

#php scriptleri languagelere dönderiyor
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/playlist\.xml$ includes/xml/mediaxml.php?album=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/(.+).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/$ http://www.dunyaturizm.com.tr/?lang=en

#Ürün Detay Sayfası
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$2&lang=tr
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$2&lang=en

#Kategori Sayfası
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ product.php?cid=$2

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Please do not completely change your question like this. If you have another question, *ask another question*. It is not fair to those who have answered your previous question to completely change it and essentially make their answers useless.

Answer (score 1):

Reorder the rules (make album rule first) and add `L` flag to it, this way rules execution will stop as soon as it matches this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/playlist\.xml$ includes/xml/mediaxml.php?album=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^includes/xml/mediaxml\.php$
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/(.+).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @CihanKüsmez the url you showed now does not match any of the rules above... it is not being rewritten (unless you didnt show all the rules)

Comment: This url (used inside the page) http://www.dunyaturizm.com.tr/album/1185/playlist.xml does hit a rewrite.... Please, show contents of the .htaccess file

Comment: @CihanKüsmez see update - added `RewriteCond` to prevent matching mediaxml.php in sub-request

Comment: of course it exists. Now i change two lines to comment. (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^includes/xml/mediaxml\.php$
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/(.+).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]) And it's working http://www.dunyaturizm.com.tr/includes/xml/mediaxml.php?album=1053

Answer (score 0):

well I am not really sure but I think if you move the album Up with the L flag should work.